# How to convert Live video stream from YUV(HDYC) to RGB

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, webcam, color-space

I want to convert video streams from webcam. that video streams are called HDYC. I think it's a little special so I didn't control now.

My question is How to convert that format to rgb in c++ using ffmpeg? but there are some constraints.
I don't want to make a file. in other wors, It needs to convert video streams from webcam. also It's a real time operation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you tagged it with [h.264](/questions/tagged/h.264), because [`HDYC`](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#HDYC) is a flavor of `UYVY` pixel format, layout and subsampling, just with [ITU-R Rec. 709](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709) defined color space.

So your question is how do you convert BT.709 YUV to RGB with FFmpeg. FFmpeg's libswscale can do this: its `sws_scale` does the conversion, and its `sws_setColorspaceDetails` lets you provide color space details for the conversion.

```
/**
 * Scale the image slice in srcSlice and put the resulting scaled
 * slice in the image in dst. A slice is a sequence of consecutive
 * rows in an image.
[...] */
int sws_scale(struct SwsContext *c, const uint8_t *const srcSlice[],
              const int srcStride[], int srcSliceY, int srcSliceH,
              uint8_t *const dst[], const int dstStride[]);

/**
[...]
 * @param table the yuv2rgb coefficients describing the output yuv space, normally ff_yuv2rgb_coeffs[x]
[...] */
int sws_setColorspaceDetails(struct SwsContext *c, const int inv_table[4],
                             int srcRange, const int table[4], int dstRange,
                             int brightness, int contrast, int saturation);
```